# Overriding a Rails default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have an ActiveRecord::Base model with a default-scope:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope :conditions => ["bar = ?",bar]

end
```

Is there any way to do a `Foo.find` *without* using the `default_scope` conditions? In other words, can you override a default scope?

I would have thought that using 'default' in the name would suggest that it **was** overridable, otherwise it would be called something like `global_scope`, right?

Comment: https://andycroll.com/ruby/dont-use-default-scope/

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Short answer: Do not use `default_scope` unless you really have to.  You'll probably be better off with named scopes.  With that said, you can use `with_exclusive_scope` to override the default scope if you need to.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648971/rails-why-is-withexclusivescope-protected-any-good-practice-on-how-to-use-it) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the previous question

Comment: > Don't use default_scope unless you really have to.

An excellent advise! Thank you!

Comment: So true. Using `default_scope` might seem like a good idea, but will likely cause multiple headaches during the lifetime of your app.

Comment: See this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087336/why-is-using-the-rails-default-scope-often-recommend-against : Why not use `default_scope`?

Comment: [`with_exclusive_scope` was removed in rails 3](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bd1666ad1de88598ed6f04ceffb8488a77be4385)

Comment: You are exaggerating a little sir. `default_scope` is an excellent tool and there are situations where you could another way but `default_scope` its just the right thing to do. For example, when you have a `Product` model that has a `inactive` flag, setting a `default_scope { where inactive: false }` is the best thing to do, since 99% or cases you will not want to display a inactive product. Then you just call `unscoped` on the remaining 1% cases, which is probably a Admin panel.

Comment: @pedrozath You could have an ActiveProduct class which inherits from Product and applies the default scope.

Comment: Default scope violates the principle of least astonishment. I'm busy cursing previous developers for using this!

Comment: the paranoid gem uses it.

Answer (score 222):

In Rails 3:

```
foos = Foo.unscoped.where(:baz => baz)
```

Comment: This has a side effect, if Post has_many Comment, Post.first.comments.unscoped returns ALL comments.

Comment: This really screwed me up for a while. Especially if you end up putting this in a class method like: `def self.random; unscoped.order('rand()'); end` unscoped removes ALL sql before it, not just what is listed under default_scope. While technically a correct answer, be careful using `unstopped`

Comment: WARNING! Unscoped does NOT remove the default_scope only, it was already said in another comment but it can really mess up with things.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to only `unscoped` when it can directly follow a model, e.g. `Foo.unscoped.blah()` is ok but never `Foo.blah().unscoped`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834159/overriding-a-rails-default-scope/58142166#58142166 works around the side effect mentioned by Enrico

Answer (score 118):

If all you need is to change the order defined in `default_scope`, you can use the [`reorder` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder).

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('created_at desc')
end

Foo.reorder('created_at asc')
```

runs the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "foos" ORDER BY created_at asc
```

Comment: Tip: define a scope like `scope :without_default_order, -> { reorder("") }` and you can do things like `Foo.without_default_order.order("created_at ASC")` In some situations it reads better (maybe not this exact situation, but I had one).

Comment: Reorder did it for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 56):

Since `4.1` you can use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#unscope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope) to fight default scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where tester: false }
  scope :testers, -> { unscope(:where).where tester: true }
  scope :with_testers, -> { unscope(:where).where tester: [true, false] }
  # ...
end
```

It is [currently](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfa53cc0fde7ca5a310673b4740ab908e8d5f38e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L331) possible to `unscope` stuff like: `:where, :select, :group, :order, :lock, :limit, :offset, :joins, :includes, :from, :readonly, :having`.

But still *please avoid using of `default_scope` if you can*. It's for your own good.

Comment: This answer should be higher

Answer (score 13):

You can override a default scope using the `with_exclusive_scope` method. So:

```
foos = Foo.with_exclusive_scope { :conditions => ["baz = ?", baz] }
```

- [`with_exclusive_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002312) documentation

Comment: Not true, it's just been moved: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/ClassMethods/with_exclusive_scope

Comment: It looks like it has been deprecated

Answer (score 11):

On Rails 5.1+ (and maybe earlier, but I've tested it works on 5.1) it is possible to unscope a specific column, which imho is the ideal solution for removing a `default_scope` in a fashion that can be used inside a named scope. In the case of the OPs `default_scope`,

```
Foo.unscope(where: :bar)
```

Or

```
scope :not_default, -> { unscope(where: :bar) }
Foo.not_default
```

Will both result in a sql query that doesn't apply the original scope, but does apply whatever other conditions get merged into the arel.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 3 default_scope does not appear to get overridden like it did in Rails 2.

e.g.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
  default_scope :order=>"created_at desc"
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
end

> Bar.foos
  SELECT * from Foo where bar_id = 2 order by "created_at desc";
> Bar.unscoped.foos
  SELECT * from Foo;  (WRONG!  removes the "has" relationship)
> Bar.foos( :order=>"created_at asc" )  # trying to override ordering
  SELECT * from Foo where bar_id = 2 order by "created_at desc, created_at asc"
```

In my app, using PostgreSQL, the ordering in the default scope WINS.  I'm removing all of my default_scopes and coding it in explicitly everywhere.

Pitfall Rails3!

Comment: You have to use `Bar.foos.reorder(:created_at => :asc)`

Answer (score 4):

With Rails 3+ you can use a combination of unscoped and merge:

```
# model User has a default scope
query = User.where(email: "foo@example.com")

# get rid of default scope and then merge the conditions
query = query.unscoped.merge(query)
```

Comment: This also worked for me, to call unscoped first (Rails 4.2): `User.unscoped.where(email: "foo@example.com")`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always use the old time favorite `find_by_sql` with the complete query. 
For example:
    Model.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM models WHERE id=123")