# My rails model won't order entries properly, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have a rails model with the following scopes:

```
 default_scope order('created_at ASC')
 scope :published, order('created_at DESC').where(:draft=>false)
```

Unfortunately, the published scope won't order the entries in descending order.

Am I writing this scope wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `:published` scope won't overwrite the default ordering unless you using `reorder`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reorder

Try

```
scope :published, where(:draft=>false).reorder('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your default scope will still fire; you can either `.reorder`, explicitly get `Foo.unscoped.published`, or use [`with_exclusive_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/with_exclusive_scope/class).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834159/overriding-a-rails-default-scope) for more details, including another SO question with more info.