# Rails ActiveRecord alternative to ModelName.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Recently I've been using `ModelName.where(nil)` in certain situations when I might use `ModelName.all`.

The difference between the two is that the former returns an ActiveRecord Relation, whereas the latter returns an array.  I can chain queries off the former, but not the latter.  I'm not pleased that I lose the self-documenting nature of `ModelName.all` though.

Is there some method like `ModelName.all` that returns an AR Relation and maintains self-documentation?

Comment: the where(nil) is a really nice workaround for always returning a relation. Maybe in the cases where you aren't sure whether or not you will return a relation or the class - you could add a class method on ActiveRecord::Base, i.e. def self.prepare; where(nil); end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelName.scoped will give you an AR relation with the default scope, ModelName.unscoped will give the the AR relation without the default scope.

Comment: I didn't know about these.  Definitely useful to know.  I'm not sure if I'll use this one since [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4166950/640517) mentions that `unscoped` can be dangerous to use on associations.  I.e. in my current project: `User.first.posts # => []` but `User.first.posts.unscoped # => all posts, by ANY user`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use `ModelName` as you can't use `all` bcz it returns array.

E.g.

```
a = ModelName
a = a.active # here active is scope
a = a.where(:deleted => false)
a = a.all
```

Comment: I don't believe I can enumerate over `ModelName` alone:  `ModelName.each {|obj| ...} # no each method defined for ModelName`.  Compare with `ModelName.where(nil).each {...}` and `ModelName.all.each {...}` Both work in case I don't need to scope deeper.

Answer (score -1):

Well I normally use

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions=>whatever, :order=>whatever,:limit=>whatever)
```

In your case maybe **Model.find(:all)** will do the trick for you

Comment: `Model.find(:all)` returns an array.  You cannot chain onto it.  Try `Model.find(:all).classMethod` for `classMethod` defined on `Model`.

Comment: I always remembered getting an array of Active record objects and I thought that was needed. My misunderstanding of the question. Thanks for telling me about it :)