# Rendering most recent articles rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Its currently listing my oldest articles at the top and I want to do the opposite. I think I need to order it as created_at somewhere but I have yet to make it work. I know this is easy but I'm still a newbie. Thanks

Currently I have

```
<div class="bit-75">
```

```
<h2 id="title"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h2>
<br>

<ul id="article-links">
  <div id="article-image"><%= image_tag article.image_url %></div>
  <br>
  <li id="article-text"><%= article.text %></li>
<br>
<%= article.created_at %>
<br>

<% if admin_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Edit',           edit_article_path(article) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Destroy',        article_path(article),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %></li>
<% else %>                
  <li><%= link_to 'Make a Comment', article_path(article) %></li>              
</ul>
<% end %>
```

article.rb

```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
   validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader                  
   end
```

articles controller

```
def new
 @article = Article.new
end

def index
 @article = Article.all
end

def create  
 @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
  redirect_to @article
else
  render 'new'
 end
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])

 if @article.update(article_params)
   redirect_to @article
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end


def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.destroy

 redirect_to articles_path
end
```

Comment: try `Article.order("created_at DESC")` in index action

Comment: Thanks Shamsul. I tried that earlier but I think I made a syntax error and it didn't work. The default_scope did work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Article model, `article.rb`, you can set a `default_scope` like this:

```
default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

However, this method will sort the articles like this on all pages. If you *only* want to sort them like this on one action, say your `def index`, then something like this might work better.

```
@articles = Article.order('created_at DESC')
```

Like @ShamsulHaque said in his comment.

Here is a good read about [default scopes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

**Update**

If you prefer to use `scopes`, like @rich says, then the syntax would look like this:

```
scope :recent, ->(order = 'desc') { order(created_at: order.to_sym) }
```

Which you would have the option, in  your controller, to call either `asc` or `desc` like so:

```
@articles = Article.recent('asc')
@articles = Article.recent('desc') # although we defaulted to 'desc', so really only need Article.recent
```

To explain a bit, @rich included the `to_sym` to convert the string `'desc'` or `'asc'` to a symbol like `:desc` or `:asc`. If you did not do this, you would get an error like

```
Direction should be :asc or :desc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked Justin. Thanks, I appreciate the help. And thanks for the link. I'll take a look.

Comment: As alternate syntax, you can also use `order(created_at: :desc)`.

Answer (score 1):

[**Scopes**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Using `default_scope` is a [little taboo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834159/overriding-a-rails-default-scope) (can cause problems) - you'll be much better using a standard scope with a condition:

```
#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :recent, (order = "desc") -> { where created_at: order.to_sym}
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@article = Article.recent("asc")
```

A nice extension to `@justin`'s answer ;)

Comment: True @rich, but should be `scope :recent, ->(order = 'desc') { order(created_at: order.to_sym) }` :)