# Creating a default value for `:order` that can be overwritten?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to create a default value for `:order`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'total_votes DESC'
```

I'm also letting users to sort the comments:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
@posts = current_user.subscribed_posts.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                :per_page => 5,
                                                :order => params[:order_by])
```

**posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<span><%= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at DESC") %></span>
<span><%= link_to 'Date (ASC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at ASC") %></span>
<span><%= link_to 'Votes', post_path(@post, :order_by => "total_votes DESC") %></span>
```

It doesn't matter which link I press, the `default_scope` is not being overwritten (it stays as `total_votes DESC` no matter what).

Is this the default behavior? If so, what's the right solution for this situation?
(I want to have a default value for `:order` but be able to change it to the value of `:order_by` once a link in `show.html.erb` is clicked).

Comment: Have you gone through these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834159/overriding-a-rails-default-scope
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648971/rails-why-is-with-exclusive-scope-protected-any-good-practice-on-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Rails 3? If so, you want either `reorder(params[:order_by])` or `except(:order).order(:order_by)` - the former was deprecated at one point (but I think then un-deprecated), the latter had a bug with default scopes in one of the Rails versions, but I forget which.

So:
`@posts = current_user.subscribed_posts.reorder(params[:order_by]).paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                :per_page => 5)`
should do the trick.