# Sorting a hash using a method from the corresponding model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

Let's say you have a model Dog with an attribute "age" a method that determines "barking frequency":

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope by_age, -> { order('age ASC') }

  def barking_frequency
    # some code
  end
end
```

In your controller you have:

```
def index
  @dogs = Dog.by_age
end
```

Once you have the hash for @dogs, how can you sort it by barking_frequency, so that the result keeps the dogs of a particular age sorted together, like this:

```
Name    Age   Barking Frequency
Molly    2    1
Buster   2    4
Jackie   2    7
Dirk     3    1
Hank     3    3
Jake     3    4
Spot     10   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will work:

```
def index
  @dogs = Dog.by_age.sort_by { |dog| [dog.age, dog.barking_frequency] }
end
```

Comment: Isn't that beautiful?

Comment: @PatriceGahide Means ? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still astounded by how beautiful and simple Ruby code can be sometimes, and I was just writing my toughts ;)

Comment: @PatriceGahide Thanks for appreciating.. :-)