# Rails not ordering by date for this query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on a website where a parent can reserve classes for their kids. In the parent's dashboard, I'd like to show a table of schedules and in every row there will be the child's name associated with a schedule. Unfortunately I have problem ordering the schedules by date in the parent's dashboard.

```
# view
<% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
  <%= reservation.child.first_name %>
  <%= reservation.schedule.date %>
  <%= reservation.schedule.start_time %> - <%= reservation.schedule.end_time %>
  <%= link_to reservation.schedule.klass.name, schedule_path(reservation.schedule) %></td>
  <%= link_to reservation.schedule.partner.company, partner_path(reservation.schedule.partner) %></td>
  <%= reservation.schedule.city.name %></td>
<% end %>

# associations
User
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :schedules, through: :reservations
Child
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :schedules, through: :reservations
Reservation
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :schedule
  belongs_to :user
Schedule
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :klass
  has_many   :reservations
  has_many   :children, through: :reservations
```

I've got a default scope in my `Schedule` model that orders by date, start_time and end_time.

```
# Schedule model
default_scope { order(:date, :start_time, :end_time) }
```

This scope works in other tables, but not for this query:

```
# controller
@reservations = current_user.reservations.includes(:child, schedule: [:partner, :klass, :city])
```

It just refuses to order by date and time in the browser:

[image: Schedule table in parent's dashboard]

The log shows that the query for Schedule is indeed being ordered:

```
Reservation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
Child Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
Schedule Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."id" IN (24, 12)  ORDER BY "schedules"."date" ASC, "schedules"."start_time" ASC, "schedules"."end_time" ASC
Partner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" IN (2)
Klass Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" WHERE "klasses"."id" IN (9, 17)
City Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" IN (28)
```

I could do this query in the controller instead:

```
@schedules = current_user.schedules
```

but then I'd have problem showing only a single child's name for each schedule since a class schedule can have many children associated for it.

Help?

Comment: The SQL generated is showing it does order the schedule

Comment: It's not super-clear to me what all is happening; you're expecting the reservations to be ordered by the schedule?

Comment: @Pavan It seems that it orders using the Reservation's database id.

Comment: I mean this `Schedule Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."id" IN (24, 12)  ORDER BY "schedules"."date" ASC, "schedules"."start_time" ASC, "schedules"."end_time" ASC`

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything that affects reservation ordering; the schedules will be ordered *within* a reservation.

Comment: @DaveNewton So that means I need to use `@schedules = current_user.schedules` instead. But if I use that how do I show only a single child's name like in the image shown above?

Comment: Well, more like it means you need to sort reservations in the way you want. I don't know how to do that anymore, but seems like it should be possible. It *certainly* is using Ruby alone, e.g., not relying on ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined an ordering on the default scope for `Schedule`, but you are pulling your relation from `Reservation`. As a result, the schedules are queried in the order specified, but since presumably you're looping through the `@reservations` in your view, you see their order and not their `schedules`'s order. You can order `@reservations` by fields on the `schedules` table like so:

```
@reservations = @reservations.order("schedules.date ASC, schedules.start_time ASC, schedules.end_time ASC")
```

Also note that defining a `default_scope` in the model is generally discouraged ([on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087336/why-is-using-the-rails-default-scope-often-recommend-against) and [elsewhere](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/)) because its difficult to manage and can cause unexpected and unintuitive effects, especially down the road.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does work: `@reservations = current_user.reservations.includes(:child, schedule: [:partner, :klass, :city]).order("schedules.date ASC, schedules.start_time ASC, schedules.end_time ASC")` but in the logs it runs a really long SQL query for 1.4ms. Is this normal?

Comment: @i.am.noob 1.4ms seems pretty fast to me. If you want to make a faster query, you may need to add better indexes to your db. If you're not sure about this, its better to make a separate question tagged with your db