# Using includes method in default_scope in Rails 5 models instead of within the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading, default-scope

I understand that generally [it is better to avoid having default scopes in Rails models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087337/7588447), however, as some associations are always needed & instead of having the `.includes` method in the controller every time for the model, I prefer having that includes in a default scope in the model itself.

**Is there any major drawback of this change (moving `.includes` to model's `default_scope` instead of controller)?**

*So for example:*

Instead of having in the controller:

`Brand.includes(:car_model)`

I want to have `includes` in the Brand model itself this:

`default_scope { includes(:car_model) }`

Note:

From what I see is that bullet is now saying **avoid eager load** to avoid this `includes` instead of the **use eager load** that I had before on the same model & included association.

Comment: I don't want to explain why. Just don't do that!

Comment: I will consider this as a joke, because for me, I do things based on good reasons only

Comment: I think because you only want to includes `car_model` on queries that will then access the relationship. I think Bullet, has found an instance where that isn't happening and therefore you should remove the default scope from the model and only use it on queries where it's needed. IMO, the problem with a default scope is just this. Instead of only using it where needed, you now have to find where it's not and using the `unscoped` helper on it to remove the default scope