# Administrate and unscoping default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-administrate

I have a model with a default scope:

```
default_scope -> { where(is_active: true) }
```

Can I unscope the model in Administrate, so the I can see all the records in the admin panel?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648971/rails-why-is-with-exclusive-scope-protected-any-good-practice-on-how-to-use-it

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
User.unscope(where: :is_active)
```

but it would probably be better to just not have a default scope if you are not going to use it everywhere.

[link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope)

Answer (score 0):

You can unscope the `where` clause using the [unscope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#overriding-conditions) method. Here's how you'd create a new scope overriding the where clause in default_scope.

```
scope :including_inactive, ->{ unscope(where: :is_active) }
```